# React Native, change select styles

Tags: react-native, select, styles

Please, help, I want to change styles for options. How can I do this?

```
<RNPickerSelect
                            placeholder={{}}
                            useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
                            style={{
                                inputIOS: styles.inputIOS,
                                inputAndroid: styles.inputAndroid,
                            }}
                            value={this.state.language}
                            onValueChange={(value) => this.onLanguageChange(value)}
                            items={[
                                { label: 'En', value: 'en' },
                                { label: 'He', value: 'he' }
                            ]}
                        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Props

Here is an Example

Here we defined in a good way for both ios and android

https://snack.expo.io/@lfkwtz/react-native-picker-select

Hope it helps , Feel free to ask Questions. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but i could change only color for options, but background-color couldn't․․․ Can you show me?